# How to get sum from textview in list layout?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm having problem with coding how to count all numbers that user inserted in TextView in ListView...

Here is my app... All I need to now is how to get the sum from rows in list view and show them in another text view:

[image]

This is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Ruka> fetch = new ArrayList<Ruka>();
    Button bt;
    EditText et;
    TextView tv;
    TextView mi;
    TextView vi;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMi);
        vi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewVi);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        // final String input = et.getText().toString();

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (et.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "test",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (Float.valueOf(et.getText().toString()) >= 12) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                String input = et.getText().toString();
                if (null != input && input.length() > 0) {
                    String maxpunti = "11";
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(maxpunti);
                    int b = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    int c = a - b;
                    String input2 = String.valueOf(c);
                    Ruka one = new Ruka(input, input2);
                    fetch.add(one);
                    et.setText("");
                    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.lista, fetch);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ruka>{
    private ArrayList<Ruka> entries;
    private Activity activity;

    public Adapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Ruka> entries) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
        this.entries = entries;
        this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView item1;
        public TextView item2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final Ruka custom = entries.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            holder.item1.setText(custom.getFirst());
            holder.item2.setText(custom.getSecond());
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

UPDATE

Here is `Ruka.java`:

```
public class Ruka {
private String customBig;
private String customSmall;

public Ruka(String string, String string2) {
this.customBig = string;
this.customSmall = string2;
}
public String getFirst() { return customBig; }
public void setcustomBig(String getFirst) { this.customBig = getFirst; }

public String getSecond() { return customSmall; }
public void setcustomSmall(String getSecond) { this.customSmall = getSecond; }
}
```

If someone can find solution... Please... Anyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say add a method to your adapter that does this:

```
public int getSum(){
  int sum;
  for(Ruka ruka: entries){
    sum += ruka.getFirst();
  }
}
```

Assuming ruka.getFirst() is a numeric value.

Comment: when I add this I got error
The method getFirst() is undefined for the type ArrayList<Ruka>
something is wrong with .getfirst :/

Comment: I added Ruka.java check it out

Comment: I didn't bother to add that you would have to parse the string as an int since you already have code that does that.  I assumed you knew you would need that.  Change sum += ruka.getFirst() to sum += Integer.parseInt(ruka.getFirst());